# Running an extension in background on page load/refresh

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to writing extensions (and javascript). I'd like an extension to run on a timer whenever a certain URL is opened/refreshed. Code is below. This is all I have so far from what I've found online. I'm not sure if this will run for just one tab at a time.

manifest.json

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Test Plugin",
  "description": "This extension is a test.",
  "version": "1.0",

    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["main.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab"
   ]
}
```

main.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && tab.active) {

    setInterval(mainF, 5000)

  }
})

    function mainF() {
        var getTitle = document.getElementById('title');
        var titleValue = getTitle.Value();

        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var fh = fso.OpenTextFile("test.txt", 8, false, 0);
        fh.WriteLine(titleValue);
        fh.Close()
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your logic to the [Event Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages).

[Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) doesn't have access to `chrome.tabs` API.

And according to [best practices when using event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#transition),

> Use [event filters](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#filtered) to restrict your event notifications to the cases you care about. For example, if you listen to the `tabs.onUpdated` event, try using the [webNavigation.onCompleted](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCompleted) event with filters instead (the tabs API does not support filters). That way, your event page will only be loaded for events that interest you.

Code snippets would look like

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test Plugin",
    "description": "This extension is a test.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["main.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions": [
        "webNavigation"
    ]
}
```

main.js

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(details){
    console.log("Certain url with hostSuffix google.com has been loaded");
}, {url: [{hostSuffix: 'google.com'}]});
```

Comment: I wonder, why *event page*? Isn't a overkill to wake up background on every tab update, which is very frequent

Comment: @WolfWar, thanks for catching that, I have updated the answer repecting best practices, using event filters and `webNavigation.onCompleted` instead.