# chrome extension - chrome.tabs.executeScript after page redirect

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a Google chrome extension that injects a script upon clicking the extension icon. However, i want the same script to be injected whenever I load/go to another page, without having to click on the extension icon again.

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
 if (tab.url.startsWith("https://")){ 
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        "file": "js/contentscript.js"
    }, function () {
        console.log("Script Executed .. "); // Notification on Completion
    });
 }
 else{
    alert('Error');
 }
});
```

manifest.json *i want to execute the script on browserAction so adding the script on content_scripts is not an option i would like to pursue*

```
"permissions": ["tabs", "windows", "notifications", "activeTab"],
"version": "2.0",
"browser_action": 
{
    "name": "Click to activate extension",
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
},
"background":
{
    "scripts":["js/background.js"]
},
"icons":
{
    "16": "images/icon16.png",
    "48": "images/icon48.png",
    "128": "images/icon128.png"
},
"content_scripts": 
[{
    "js": ["js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"],
    "matches": [ "https://*/*" ],
    "run_at": "document_end"
}]
```

contenscript.js - *only a sample script, but gets my point across*

```
alert("here");
setTimeout(function(){window.open("www.google.com");});
```

P.S. This is my first time asking a question in stackoverflow, please be gentle with me. :D

Comment: What do you mean when you are saying "page redirect"? Do you mean whenever a new url is loaded or just [redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection) happens?

Comment: Whenever a new url is loaded. I'm sorry. I'll edit my question.

Comment: I tried passing a message from the script to the background page before window.open() and then set a timeout before running chrome.tabs.executeScript. Am I getting close? Or. . .

Comment: you could just listen to `webNavigation.onCompleted` event in background page, see my answer if it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could listen to [webNavigation.onCompleted](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCompleted) event, which fires when a document, including the resources it refers to, is completely loaded and initialized.

Compared with [tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) event, you could use [event filters](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#filtered) to restrict your event notifications. For this part, you could check my answer in this post [Running an extension in background on page load/refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682603/running-an-extension-in-background-on-page-load-refresh/36683872#36683872) for more details.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "36735306",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Your description here",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": ["content.js"],
    "permissions": [
        "webNavigation",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
    if(details.frameId === 0) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, {"file": "content.js"}); 
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this. But it seems to fire more than twice. Any suggestions?

Comment: @izzy00, that's because sub frame also triggers that, you could add frameId check. I have updated the answer, frameId ===0 means navigation happens in the tab content window

Comment: That did it. I added some extra conditions and events. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: @izzy00, glad to know that, you could also use event filters to be noticed only for the cases you care about, otherwise there may be many times the event page is recalled, then the advantage `webNavigation.onCompleted` than `tabs.onUpdated` may not be made use of.